# Combining two tables and outputting dates horizontally PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpexcel

My first table `list_info`

```
list_id | list_name   |   list_link  |    list_extrafee     | list_reviews
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 4852   |  List One   |    /list1    |   $4 after 3 guests  |    56
 4853   |  List Two   |    /list2    |   $10 after 5 guests |     42
 4854   |  List Three |    /list3    |   $40 after 8 guests |     32
 4855   |  List Four  |    /list4    |         FREE         |    14
```

Second table `list_price`

```
list_id  |  dates        | list_price  | list_avilable
------------------------------------------------------
4852     | 4/12/2015     |     55      |     TRUE
4852     | 5/12/2015     |     56      |     TRUE
4852     | 6/12/2015     |     89      |     TRUE
4852     | 7/12/2015     |     110     |     TRUE
4852     | 8/12/2015     |     150     |     TRUE
4852     | 9/12/2015     |     110     |     TRUE
4852     | 10/12/2015    |     110     |     TRUE
4852     | 11/12/2015    |     150     |     TRUE
4852     | 12/12/2015    |     110     |     TRUE
4853     | 4/12/2015     |     160     |     TRUE
4853     | 5/12/2015     |     140     |     FALSE
4853     | 6/12/2015     |     55      |     FALSE
4853     | 7/12/2015     |     56      |     FALSE
4853     | 8/12/2015     |     89      |     FALSE
4853     | 9/12/2015     |     110     |     FALSE
4853     | 10/12/2015    |     150     |     FALSE
4853     | 11/12/2015    |     110     |     FALSE
4853     | 12/12/2015    |     110     |     FALSE
4854     | 4/12/2015     |     150     |     TRUE
4854     | 5/12/2015     |     110     |     TRUE
4854     | 6/12/2015     |     160     |     TRUE
4854     | 7/12/2015     |     140     |     TRUE
4854     | 8/12/2015     |     160     |     TRUE
4854     | 9/12/2015     |     180     |     TRUE
4854     | 10/12/2015    |     110     |     TRUE
4854     | 11/12/2015    |     110     |     TRUE
4854     | 12/12/2015    |     50      |     TRUE
4855     | 4/12/2015     |     50      |     TRUE
4855     | 5/12/2015     |     48      |     TRUE
4855     | 6/12/2015     |     60      |     TRUE
4855     | 7/12/2015     |     70      |     TRUE
4855     | 8/12/2015     |     65      |     TRUE
4855     | 9/12/2015     |     90      |     TRUE
4855     | 10/12/2015    |     80      |     TRUE
4855     | 11/12/2015    |     70      |     TRUE
4855     | 12/12/2015    |     60      |     TRUE
```

What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

So far I've managed to get only one of the tables into an array and passing it with the `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray();` function, code:

```
public function scrape()
{
    /** Error reporting */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    /** Include path **/
    ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../Classes/');

    /** PHPExcel */
    include 'PHPExcel.php';

    /** PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007 */
    include 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';// Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    // Set properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("AB")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("AB")
        ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
        ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
        ->setDescription("AB document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
        ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
        ->setCategory("AB result file");
    // Add some data

    $q = $this->db->select('*')->from('list_info')->get();
    $sheet=$q->result_array();


    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($sheet);


    // Rename sheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('AB Result '.date('d-m-Y').'');
    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // Redirect output to a clients web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
```

I need help combining those two tables into an array that will be suitable for generating the example excel file i have uploaded..

### ERROR in Somnath Muluk's answer

```
Error
```

SQL query:

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql ;

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `list_info` l JOIN list_price p ON l.list_id = p.list_id
      ' at line 15
```

LONG WORKING CODE:

```
SELECT l.*,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-11-29" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-11-29" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-11-29`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-11-30" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-11-30" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-11-30`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-01" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-01" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-01`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-02" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-02" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-02`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-03" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-03" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-03`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-04" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-04" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-04`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-05" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-05" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-05`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-06" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-06" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-06`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-07" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-07" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-07`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-08" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-08" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-08`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-09" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-09" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-09`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-10" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-10" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-10`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-11" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-11" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-11`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-12" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-12" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-12`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-13" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-13" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-13`,

   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-14" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-14" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-14`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-15" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-15" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-15`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-16" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-16" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-16`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-17" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-17" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-17`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-18" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-18" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-18`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-19" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-19" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-19`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-20" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-20" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-20`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-21" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-21" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-21`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-22" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-22" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-22`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-23" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-23" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-23`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-24" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-24" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-24`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-25" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-25" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-25`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-26" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-26" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-26`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-27" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-27" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-27`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-28" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-28" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-28`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-29" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-29" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-29`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-30" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-30" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-30`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-31" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2015-12-31" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2015-12-31`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-01" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-01" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-01`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-02" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-02" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-02`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-03" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-03" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-03`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-04" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-04" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-04`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-05" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-05" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-05`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-06" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-06" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-06`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-07" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-07" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-07`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-08" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-08" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-08`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-09" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-09" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-09`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-10" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-10" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-10`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-11" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-11" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-11`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-12" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-12" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-12`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-13" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-13" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-13`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-14" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-14" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-14`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-15" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-15" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-15`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-16" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-16" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-16`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-17" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-17" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-17`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-18" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-18" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-18`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-19" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-19" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-19`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-20" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-20" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-20`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-21" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-21" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-21`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-22" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-22" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-01-22`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-01-23" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-05-21`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-22" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-22" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-05-22`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-23" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-23" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-05-23`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-24" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-24" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-05-24`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-25" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-25" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-05-25`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-26" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-26" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-05-26`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-27" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-27" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-05-27`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-28" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-28" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-05-28`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-29" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-29" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-05-29`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-30" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-30" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-05-30`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-31" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-05-31" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-05-31`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-06-01" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-06-01" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-06-01`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-06-02" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-06-02" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-06-02`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-06-03" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-06-03" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-06-03`,
   MAX( CASE
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-06-04" and p.list_available = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price
        WHEN p.list_date = "2016-06-04" and p.list_available = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE')
        ELSE NULL END) `2016-06-04`
FROM `airbnb_lists` l JOIN airbnb_lists_price p ON l.list_id = p.list_id
GROUP   BY l.list_id
```

Comment: join two tables using JOIN  while fetching result using SELECT clause.In this way you can get desired result.

Comment: @naruto i know this but i am trying to get a specific horizontal layout for the dates with prices

Answer (score 4):

I have created [demo database](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/db_structure.php?server=2&db=somnath&token=8d2dbab95fadfa984fc94caa6ba7083e) for you & also added only some dummy data in tables.

You need to find out different dates which are available from list_price.

If you want dynamic columns from list_price then you can run following query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX( CASE
            WHEN p.dates = "', dates,'" and p.list_avilable = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price 
            WHEN p.dates = "', dates,'" and p.list_avilable = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , " FALSE") 
            ELSE NULL END) as `', dates,'`
           ' )
    )
FROM list_price
```

Which will give you dynamic columns:

```
  MAX( CASE
       WHEN p.dates = "4/12/2015" and p.list_avilable = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price 
       WHEN p.dates = "4/12/2015" and p.list_avilable = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , " FALSE") 
       ELSE NULL END) as `4/12/2015`,
  MAX( CASE
       WHEN p.dates = "5/12/2015" and p.list_avilable = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price 
       WHEN p.dates = "5/12/2015" and p.list_avilable = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , " FALSE") 
       ELSE NULL END) as `5/12/2015`
```

And need to make a query like below.

```
// $columns will have result of first query.
$query= "SELECT l.*,
          ".$columns."
          FROM `list_info` l JOIN list_price p ON l.list_id = p.list_id
         GROUP BY l.list_id";
```

You query will be like.

```
SELECT l.*,
       MAX( CASE
            WHEN p.dates = "4/12/2015" and p.list_avilable = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price 
            WHEN p.dates = "4/12/2015" and p.list_avilable = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE') 
            ELSE NULL END) `4/12/2015`,
       MAX( CASE 
            WHEN p.dates = "5/12/2015" and p.list_avilable = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price 
            WHEN p.dates = "5/12/2015" and p.list_avilable = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , ' FALSE') 
            ELSE NULL END) `5/12/2015`
    FROM `list_info` l JOIN list_price p ON l.list_id = p.list_id
    GROUP   BY l.list_id
```

I was able to find result like:

[image]

## Update:

**Or** You can combine both sql query to one. You just need to replace `$q = $this->db->select('*')->from('list_info')->get();` this with following raw query statement.

```
SET @sql= '';
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                    CONCAT('MAX( CASE
                           WHEN p.dates = "', dates,'" and p.list_avilable = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price 
                           WHEN p.dates = "', dates,'" and p.list_avilable = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , " FALSE") 
                           ELSE NULL END) as `', dates,'`
                           ' )
                   ) INTO @sql
FROM list_price;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT l.*, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM `list_info` l JOIN list_price p ON l.list_id = p.list_id
                  GROUP   BY l.list_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Some issues with this query in PHPMyadmin. Just shows rows count. Check if you get result in PHP.

Comment: This is might be what i am looking for, however. How can i select ALL dates and join them?

Comment: @IlanHasanov : I have updated answer to get columns dynamically and put into your final query of output.

Comment: I have about 189000 Records in my list_price so i need some way of selecting and JOIN everything together :) Not really sure how to combine those two queries?

Comment: Could you help me wrap those Queries in PHP Please

Comment: @IlanHasanov: I have updated again with combined query. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Somnath, I am getting empty set with your demo database and unrecognized statement type DEALLOCATE error

Comment: @IlanHasanov: Try without `DEALLOCATE` statement. Don't know what's problem with PHP Myadmin. PHP admin have some problem with EXCEUTE. It gives only rows count. Check in PHP. Or you can still go with option 1

Comment: Could you please see the error i have posted in my Question. that i am getting now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97187/discussion-between-ilan-hasanov-and-somnath-muluk).

Comment: My SQL date column is actually date and not varchar.. my dates looks like 2015-11-29 2015-11-30 etc maybe thats the reason the sql not working

Comment: Is this solution working? If my answer solves your problem, you can accept my answer. So I will get auto bounty after bounty expiring. Don't award bounty soon. Let's check if there is any easy way to do this.

Comment: see the code i posted it works but very very long how can i make it short?

Comment: @IlanHasanov: It's not actually long query. As you require to show that many columns (one column for each date), then that's the final query you need to run anyhow. If you can minimise the columns to display then query can be made short by removing columns i.e date you don't want to show.

Comment: And how can i generate this long code to run it? because i made it manually. and if more days added to database they will not display untill i manually add

Comment: @IlanHasanov : You will get that query by first query I gave of GROUP_CONCAT.
`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT('MAX( CASE
            WHEN p.dates = "', dates,'" and p.list_avilable = "TRUE" THEN p.list_price 
            WHEN p.dates = "', dates,'" and p.list_avilable = "FALSE" THEN CONCAT( p.list_price , " FALSE") 
            ELSE NULL END) as `', dates,'`
           ' )
    )
FROM list_price`

Comment: It is returning me Showing rows 0 - 29 (160650 total, Query took 0.4383 sec) from PhpmyAdmin MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). because dates is date and not varchar and CASE WHEN p.dates = "', dates,'" doesn't know what is dates... how can i fix it

Comment: It sort of solve my problem. only if i create the long SQL statment it works. i cannot generate this code via a statment